# How to get device's maximum refresh rate in flutter?

Tags: flutter

My widget uses `TickerProviderStateMixn` and `AnimationController` to animate `CustomPaint`. and whenever `AnimationController` updates `CustomPaint`, it also updates data handler class by calling `update()` method in this data handler.

This widget contains player thing, and whenever `update()` is called, I made player bar move specific amount of x position. Player also has to show time value, basically, player bar's position indicates how time passes. So time value is displayed along player bar's position. I thought flutter supports only 60 fps, meaning `update()` is called 60 times per second, I made player bar move `X/60` whenever `update()` is called. `X` is just any value, if time becomes 1 second when player bar reaches position of 100, then `X` will be 100.

But recently, I changed my phone to new one, and this device can support 120fps, and it seems `AnimationController` tries to animate widget with this max capable refresh rate. So `update()` is now called 120 times per second, and everything is done twice faster. I want to make data handler able to get maximum refresh rate, so it can synchronize player bar moving with device's screen. If device's max refresh rate is 60fps, then handler will make bar move `X/60` per call, and if device can support 120fps, then it will make bar move `X/120` per call, and so on.

To achieve this, I need to pass device's display's max capable refresh rate to data handler. I tried to google it, but I couldn't find any helpful posts or codes which tells the way to get this info.

Is there any way to get maximum refresh rate in flutter?
Or are there any plugins which can provide such info?

Edit:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:test_app/util/core/TestPainter.dart';
import 'package:test_app/util/core/cubit/TestData.dart';
import 'package:test_app/widget/EditPanel.dart';
import 'package:test_app/widget/Editor.dart';

class EditorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  EditorPage({required this.sh, required this.sw});

  final double sh;
  final double sw;

  @override
  EditorStatus createState() => EditorStatus();
}

class EditorStatus extends State<EditorPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late TestPainter painter;
  late TestData data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    _controller.repeat();

    data = TestData(widget.sh * 0.85, widget.sw, _controller);

    painter = TestPainter(data: data, animated: _controller);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<TestData>.value(
      value: data,
      child: Scaffold(
          body: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 1,
            heightFactor: 1,
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: widget.sh * 0.15,
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Editor(
                      sh: widget.sh,
                      sw: widget.sw,
                      painter: painter,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: widget.sh * 0.15 / 3,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    height: widget.sh * 0.1,
                    child: EditPanel(widget.sw, widget.sh * 0.1),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

So basically widget called `Editor` and `EditPanel` require data handler called `TestData`, and painter called `TestPainter`. `TestData` requires `_controller` to manipulate `TestPainter`'s animating status by calling `repeat()` and `stop()`. By status of widget (whether user is touching/scaling/long touching/etc widget or not, or whether buttons in `EditPanel` is clicked or not), `_controller` animates widget or stops animating it. `TestPainter` requires `TestData` as variable (I know now `TestPainter` can access `_controller`, but as long as I make `TestPainter` not touch `_controller`, it should be fine?), and it updates data whenever `paint` method is called. Even though data updating code is called, data's result differs from widget's *status*

For example,

```dart
return IconButton(
  splashRadius: sh * 0.75 / 3,
  icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: ThemeManager.getRGBfromHex(0x77d478),),
  onPressed: () {
    if (!data.playing) {
      data.setStatus(Status.playing);
    }
  },
);
```

In `EditPanel`, this play button calles `data`, which is `TestData`, and in `TestData`,

```dart
void setStatus(Status st) {
  if(st == Status.idle) {
    pause();
    stopVelocity();
    current = st;
    if(!blockAnimating) {
      controller.stop();
    }
  } else if(st == Status.playing) {
    play();
    controller.repeat();
    current = st;
  } else if(st == Status.sliding) {
    current = st;
    controller.repeat();
  } else if(st == Status.reversing) {
    reverse();
    controller.repeat();
    current = st;
  } else if(st == Status.selecting) {
    current = st;
    controller.repeat();
  }

  if(blockAnimating) {
    controller.repeat();
  }
}
```

As you can see, if `st` is `playing`, it calls `controller.repeat()`, which is `AnimationController` stored in `TestData`.

So if player status is `playing`, `_controller` will repeat itself, resulting in calls of `paint` method in `TestPainter`. Then `TestPainer` calls `_handlePlaying()` by calling `updateData(Size s)` method in `paint`, so animation with data updating can be done with `AnimationController`. Whenever `paint` is called, data gets updated, so each `paint` will result in different appearance (or may be not depending on status of player. If player is on idle, then it will draw same. Actually, it won't draw at all because `controller.stop()` will be called).

```dart
void updateData(Size s) {
  sh = s.height;
  sw = s.width;

  if(current == Status.playing) {
    _handlePlaying();
  } else if(current == Status.selecting) {
    updateSelectMode();
  } else if(current == Status.sliding) {
    performVelocity();
  } else if(current == Status.reversing) {
    _handleReverse();
  }

  _handleBlockAnimation();
}

void _handlePlaying() {
  if(playPos == ((_lastBlock?.row ?? 0) + 48) * blockSize) {
    setStatus(Status.idle);
    return;
  }

  double upf = tick * blockSize / frames; //Here

  playPos += upf;

  if(playPos - posX >= sw - sh * 0.075) {
    posX += upf;
  }

  updatePlayer();

  if(posX > endPosX) {
    posX = endPosX;
  }

  if(playPos > (( _lastBlock?.row ?? 0) + 48) * blockSize) {
    playPos = ((_lastBlock?.row ?? 0) + 48) * blockSize;
  }
}
```

`playPos` is player bar's position, and `upf` (unit per frame) is amount of x-pos which bar has to move per frame. So in this code `X` will be `tick * blockSize`, and `frames` is 60 initially. By tweaking this `frames` variable, I can make players move slower or faster per frame. If I set `frames` to 120 on device whose display can support 120 fps, then player is synced with real-time, but on 60fps display, player gets twice slower. On opposite, if I set `frames` to 60, then player is synced with real-time, and on 120 fps device, player gets twice faster.

I know this synchronization will be broken if fps goes lower than 60. I'm aware of this. I checked that my widget can be run with 60 fps with debug mode with slow device, so it should run faster on release mode in future. Let's skip this.

```dart
@override
void paint(Canvas cv, Size s) {
  //Somewhere of codes in TestPainter

  data.updateData(s);

  //Keep going
}
```

Comment: It appears you’re asking the wrong question here. The built-in animation tools take framerate into consideration, and the way you’re animating it would also cause the animation to slack behind whenever the app runs into a snag—not good. Can you provide your code?

Comment: @JediBurrell I added some my source codes to show how things work. I feel I'm doing something wrong though, yeah. `AnimationController` manipulates `TestPainter`, `TestPainter` manipulates `TestData`, and `TestData` manipulates `AnimationController`. They are calling each others, but `TestPainter` never manipulates `AnimationController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flutter_displaymode](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_displaymode) plugin to fetch the device's display refresh rate. The plugin also allows to set the devices preferred display mode but it has limitations depending on the device.

You can fetch the supported display modes using `FlutterDisplayMode.supported` to identify the max refresh rate.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_displaymode/flutter_displaymode.dart';
import 'dart:math';

try {
  List<DisplayMode> modes = await FlutterDisplayMode.supported;
  List<double> refreshRateList = [];
  
  // fetch list of display modes available in the device
  modes.forEach((DisplayMode mode){
    refreshRateList.add(mode.refreshRate);
  });
  
  // if refreshRateList is not empty, fetch max refresh rate
  if(!refreshRateList.isEmpty) {
    // print max refresh rate
    debugPrint('${refreshRateList.reduce(max)}');
  }
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  /// e.code =>
  /// noAPI - No API support. Only Marshmallow and above.
  /// noActivity - Activity is not available. Probably app is in background
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it using `Display`.

```dart
var display = WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.display;
print('${display.refreshRate} fps'); // 120 fps
```